# Need to do a custom preference center for Marketing Cloud and am wondering if it's better to use Cloud Pages or an Experience Cloud site to do it?

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, experience-cloud, unsubscribe, preference-center

I have a Marketing Cloud instance with multiple Business Units so need to create custom preference center.  I was planning to do it using Cloud Pages and AmpScript, but heard you can also create the same type of pref page using an Experience Cloud site and use Omni Script for it? I would be handling subscribes/unsubscribes from multiple BU's with multiple newsletters/interest area subscriptions. Is there a reason to keep the Preference Center on the MC side vs the Salesforce side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce's vision for this (as presented at CNX 2022) is to have a Global Privacy Center hosted in Experience Cloud -- so it can directly maintain the consent object data across *any* sending channel.

Then the synchronized data through the MCE connector can be used to qualify any batch queries for email, SMS and Push messaging.  The consent API endpoint could be used to cover consent enforcement for real-time messages.

I've yet to see this in the wild, however.  Experience Cloud development seems way more involved/structured than standing up a custom preference center in CloudPages.  The problem lies in replicating consent logic, if you decide to go down that route.